# how to zip folder inside it two folders using ZipArchive class

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to zip folder it call

Maker_100164 inside this folder two folders and two files
folder_a
folder_b
index1.php
index.php

and I'm using below function

```
function Zip($source, $destination)
{
    if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
        return false;
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
        return false;
    }

    $source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));

    if (is_dir($source) === true)
    {
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

            // Ignore "." and ".." folders
            if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), array('.', '..')) )
                continue;

            $file = realpath($file);

            if (is_dir($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
            }
            else if (is_file($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
            }
        }
    }
    else if (is_file($source) === true)
    {
        $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
    }

    return $zip->close();
}
```

and when I want to call it I call it like this

```
$dirp = '/maker/up/users/admin/Maker_100164/';
                         $p = '/maker/up/users/admin/Maker_100164/Maker_100164.zip';

            $zipallfolders = Zip($dirp, $p);
            if($zipallfolders)
            {
                echo 'ok';
            }else{
                echo 'wrong';
                }
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to explain how it "doesn't work". Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: Your function works perfectly for me. Either `/maker/up/users/admin/Maker_100164/` doesn't exist, it isn't readable, or you don't have the zip extension. What kind of system are you running this code on?

Comment: thank you for your answer i found the problem it was from path when i change the path function work without any problem.

thanks & best regards